# Laptop battery is discharged even when laptop is turned off

Tags: laptop, battery

I have a new Lenovo laptop.
When battery was 100% i turned the laptop off.
I did not power on for about 20 days.
After that , i turn on the laptop and i've seen that battery was 1%.
I've contacted with lenovo and they says that if the Fast Startup option is enabled , this is the cause of discharging the battery because even when laptop is off ,Fast startup requires power.
But i'm not conviced with this response ,because what about a desktop pc that has Fast Startup enabled , and when it turn off and disconnected from power ,there's no battery at all , and how Fast startup works in this case ???!!!

Is there any other cause ?

Comment: I would not be convinced either. See if they will replace the battery.

Comment: @John  No , the battery works very well , it Charge , and can keep the laptop running for about 4 hours. But has only this problem that discharge when laptop is off. So you think the battery is damaged and should be replaced ? But Lenovo insist that Fast startup is the cause and if you turn off everything will be ok ???!!!! They  offer me these solutions : https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-s-series-netbooks/s340-14iwl/solutions/ht509457-battery-may-discharge-when-laptop-is-powered-off-or-in-a-sleep-state-thinkpad-ideapad

Comment: I have had Lenovo Laptops with Fast Start enabled and that does not kill a battery. Maybe the machine should be serviced.

Comment: @john the article recommended by lenovo , in the link i've posted speak only about ThinkPad and IdeaPad. Your laptop was one of these ?

Comment: Mine are ThinkPad X1 machines and no issue with them.

Comment: It seems that someone has replaced the battery from lenovo and this did not help.https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-1xx-3xx-5xx-7xx-Edge-LaVie-Z-Flex-Laptops/Battery-Drain-while-shut-down/m-p/5195404 ."""It has always been clear to me the problem is that the machine does not go into a true power-down state when SHUT DOWN. It instead is going into one of the partially-on sleep states, slowly draining the battery."""

Comment: Next time you shut down, use the command `shutdown /s /t/ 0` to ensure complete shutdown, rather than **sleep**, which *does* use power. Wait a day, and see how much power is lost after reboot. It's normal for a laptop to drop 10 or 15% / week, though. On laptops with removable batteries, take them out before long-term storage.